# IsNullorEmpty combobox.selectedvalue

Tags: c#, combobox, isnullorempty

I am trying to set a combobox.selectedValue to a string which works but when its nullorempty it errors out.  I have tried the following code to no avail:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(docRelComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()))
        {
            document = "other";
        }

        else
        {
            document = docRelComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
```

The combobox is databound but in theory it could be nullorempty in certain situations and I need to be able to pass the other value at those times.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need:

```
if ((docRelComboBox.SelectedValue==null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(docRelComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()))
```

Since `SelectedValue` itself might be null.

Comment: thank you soo much that was driving me crazy!  I did not even think about needing to check selectedvalue in itself.

Comment: @korrowan: np, very common mistake until you get it

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ToString()` when the `SelectedValue` is null is probably causing the error. I would try:

```
if (docRelComboBox.SelectedValue == null ||
      string.IsNullOrEmpty(docRelComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()))
{
   document = "other";
}
else
{
   document = docRelComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

instead.